# Django REST Framework Viewset returns a 404 (GET request)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm seeking to understand how the ViewSet compliments URL routing when used with routers in the context of Django REST framework. When I'm requesting a collection at `api/v2/people/`, a 404 response is returned. I'm not clear on what else is required for the view to render in the browser and get a 200 status code as a part of the response?

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include

from rest_framework import routers

from people import views

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'people', views.PersonViewSet, basename="people")

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-path/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/v2/people/', include(router.urls), name="people")
]
```

**people/views.py**

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSet

from .models import Person
from .serializers import PersonSerializer


class PersonViewSet(ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Person.objects.all()
        serializer = PersonSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per your configuration, It should try this URL **`api/v2/people/people/`**

---

Or  change

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-path/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/v2/', include(router.urls), name="people") # removed `people/`
]
```

and then access **`api/v2/people/`**

Answer (score 0):

You probabely have defined you app level urls.py like this,

```
# your app level urls.py
urlpatterns = [
            .....
            .....
            path('people/',<Your view>, name='people-list'),
        ]
```

and in your root urls.py,

```
# your root level urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    .......
    path('api/v2/people/', include(router.urls), name="people")
]
```

so after appending both, the final url endpoint is,
`api/v2/people/people/`

but your are requesting `api/v2/people/`

so either remove `people/` from your root urls.py like this,

```
# your root level urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    .......
    path('api/v2/', include(router.urls), name="people")
]
```

and then request `api/v2/people/`

**OR**, request with `api/v2/people/people/`

**OR**, remove `people/` from your app level urls.py,

```
# your app level urls.py
urlpatterns = [
  .....
  .....
  path('',<Your view>, name='people-list'), # this is not a good option though
```

]

and then request `api/v2/people/`